# Install error on mxnet

Tags: r, mxnet

I am trying to install mxnet for use with R Studio on my Windows 10 laptop.

I used these instuctions:

```
install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
install.packages("mxnet")
```

But when I try this:

```
require(mxnet)
```

I get the error message:

```
Loading required package: mxnet
Error : object ‘combine_edges’ is not exported by 'namespace:DiagrammeR'
```

Here is the complete console:

```
> install.packages("drat", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/bill_/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/drat_0.1.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 73095 bytes (71 KB)
downloaded 71 KB

package ‘drat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\bill_\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIDZk6c\downloaded_packages
> drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
> install.packages("mxnet")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/bill_/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://dmlc.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/mxnet_0.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 5196542 bytes (5.0 MB)
downloaded 5.0 MB

package ‘mxnet’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\bill_\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIDZk6c\downloaded_packages
> require(mxnet)
Loading required package: mxnet
Error : object ‘combine_edges’ is not exported by 'namespace:DiagrammeR'
>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

***SOLUTION FOUND PER AXEMAN'S SUGGESTION...***

```
# version 0.9.0 of DiagrammeR won't work with mxnet at this time (20170104)
require(devtools)
install_version("DiagrammeR", version = "0.8.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: `DiagrammeR` got an update yesterday which breaks a lot of it's dependencies. The new binaries aren't out yet. Check if your versions of `mxnet` and `Diagrammer` are compatible.

Comment: Thanks Axeman! I never would have found my mistake then!  :-)  Any idea when the new binaries would be out?

Comment: A quick check reveals that `combine_edges` is in the old version of `DiagrammeR`, so I guess you already have the new version (0.9.0). I think you'll need to downgrade. You should let the maintainers of `mxnet` know, since they are [not listed](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DiagrammeR/index.html) as a reverse dependency and might not know about the update.

Comment: I did this and it worked. Thanks again Axeman!

    # version 0.9.0 of DiagrammeR won't work with mxnet at this time (20170104)
    require(devtools)
    install_version("DiagrammeR", version = "0.8.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

Comment: I have created issue in MXNet to track this - https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/4527

Answer (score 1):

With latest repo, you should be able to complete installation. They have removed references to "combine_edges" which was removed from latest DiagrammeR.

Comment: actually, just downloaded it for R, and still getting that exact error (jan 16th2016)